# Is there a possibility to automate the rotation of Azure storage SAS token using PoweShell

Tags: token, azure-storage

I'm using Azure storage, for accessing it , I'm using SAS token.

1. I would like to know if there is a way to automate the regeneration of a new SAS token after the old one has expired.
   I know there is a possibility to automatically regenerate Storage keys by using a key Vault to manage the storage account, but is this also possible for SAS tokens?
   the following link explain how to rotate key automatically but I could not find anything about SAS token: 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys
2. in addition I found this link which explain about SAS definition, can someone clarify what is it?
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/set-azurekeyvaultmanagedstoragesasdefinition?view=azurermps-6.13.0 
   , can it help me ?

Comment: Have you tried this cmdlet [New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageaccountsastoken?view=azurermps-6.13.0)? It's easy to generate a storage sas token.

Answer (score 0):

There is an azure powershell cmdlet [New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageaccountsastoken?view=azurermps-6.13.0) used to create an account-level SAS token.

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName account_name -StorageAccountKey account_key

#you can modify the code below as per your need, like expire time, resourceType etc.
New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service blob,file,table,queue -ResourceType service,container,object -Permission "racwdlup" -Context $context
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I meant more to an automated process where I don't need to run it every time the SAS taken is expired.

Comment: @kokoa, can you please explain more about it?